# Reading in binary file and using data correctly

Tags: c, binaryfiles, endianness

I am trying to write a C program to display the content of a binary file which contains a few numbers stored as follows:
*The first 4 bytes contain an integer n stored in little endian format.
The next 8n bytes contain an array of n floating point numbers stored in 8 byte double precision format*

"Data" was made with matlab, and this file includes: n = 7 array = [.7147, -.2050, -.1241, 1.4897, 1.4090, 1.4172, .6715]

So far this is the code that I have. Essentially I am trying to read in the file, send those variables through my little endian function, and display it. I'm not sure why I'm getting the outcome that I'm getting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* function to show bytes in memory, from location str to str+n*/
void extract_little(char *str,int offs, int n); 
void extract_big(char *str,int offs, int n);
/*Main function to call above function */
int ofset;

int main(){


int x;
int i[numE*4];
FILE* fp = fopen("data","rb");

fread(i,sizeof(i[x]),numE,fp);
fclose(fp);
for (x=1; x < numE;x++)
printf("%d%\n",i[x]);

//extract_little((char *)&i, ofset, sizeof(i));

  return 0;

}


  void extract_little(char *str,int offs, int n) 
    {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
       printf(" %04f\n\n", (unsigned int) str[i]);
      }

    }
```

#### New Outcome

```
-2103482977
1072095020
-359136765
-1077265325
-1953332745
-1077950484
```

Not 100% sure if this is correct, but it's a start. Unfortunately not utilizing the function, which it needs to.

Comment: This is wrong on *multiple* levels. Reading a `double` as binary, passing the size of an `int` being the lead off on that list. Reading **seven** `int` values into the address of a **single** double: *totally* undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong version. I've been playing around with this for awhile so things are getting confusing. I just fixed it with the subtle changes. I is now and int and unsigned int in the printf. However, I'm still getting an error that I'm unable to figure out how to fix.

Comment: Even after your "fix", reading *seven* items the size of an `int` into the address of a *single* `int` invokes undefined behavior. And `extract_little` is still wrong. Casting a single `char` to `unsigned int` is supported, but printing it as a *float* is not. You need to review your notes on data extraction. You should be reading four `unsigned char`, then use bitwise ops to manufacture a platform-`int` from those four bytes to acquire `n`, then allocate space for `n` `double` elements and read the remainder of the data into said-allocated buffer.

Comment: Okay, I went through and did a clean search and print not using my function at all. I (think) this is correct, not actually sure because the numbers are so strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of doubles needs to be created. Since the size is recorded in the file and is not known in advance, I dynamically allocated the memory for the array.

If the machine is also little-endian no conversion is necessary, but if it is big-endian the bytes must be reversed. To check if the machine is big-endian, the first byte of a known number can be inspected. It is possible (although very unlikely) for ints and doubles do have different endianness on the same system, so both should be checked.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// For detecting endianess.
// dummy_int: highest order byte is zero, lowest order byte is non-zero.
// dummy_double: highest order byte (part of exponent) is non-zero,
// lowest order byte (part of mantissa) is zero.
int32_t dummy_int = 1;
double dummy_double = 1.0;
#define INT_IS_BIG_ENDIAN (((char*) &dummy_int)[0] == 0)
#define DOUBLE_IS_BIG_ENDIAN (((char*) &dummy_double)[0] != 0)

void extract(FILE* fp, void *data, size_t size, int reverse);
void reverse_bytes(void *data, size_t size);
void display(void *data, size_t size);

int main()
{
    int32_t n, i;
    double *data;
    FILE* fp = fopen("data","rb");

    extract(fp, &n, sizeof(n), INT_IS_BIG_ENDIAN);
    data = (double*) malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        extract(fp, &data[i], sizeof(double), DOUBLE_IS_BIG_ENDIAN);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    // print the data
    printf("n: %d\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("item #%d: %f\n", i+1, data[i]);
        printf("in hex: ");
        display(&data[i], sizeof(double));
    }

    free(data);

    return 0;
}

void extract(FILE* fp, void *data, size_t size, int reverse)
{
    fread(data, size, 1, fp);
    if (reverse) {
        reverse_bytes(data, size);
    }
}

void reverse_bytes(void *data, size_t size)
{
    char *i, *j;
    char tmp;
    for (i = (char*) data, j = i + size - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        tmp = *i;
        *i = *j;
        *j = tmp;
    }
}

void display(void *data, size_t size)
{
    size_t i;
    char *char_data = (char*) data;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", (unsigned char) char_data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Holy cow, that's a lot to take in. Thank you so much! I'm going to be analyzing this for the rest of my night. Hopefully I can finally get this stuff through my thick skull.

Comment: Can you explain how this actually figures out the size of n?

Comment: The variable `n` is associated with four bytes of memory. The first four bytes of the input are read directly into that memory by passing the address of `n` to `fread()`. On a little-endian machine this is all that needs to be done. On a big-endian machine the four bytes must be reversed, since the machine expects the lowest order byte to be stored in the last memory location rather than the first. The reversal is done by pretending that `n` is a `char` array and swapping corresponding elements (1st with 4th, 2nd with 3rd).